# GROUPING SETS Vs GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, grouping

I have a query that intersects with a function that pulls out exception information in a banking system.  Each one of those exceptions has a huge amount of information and I am looking for a proper way to Group and/or union my work so that is comes out properly.
My SQL is as follows:

```
SELECT cb.loanNumber, cb.customerName, cb.borrowerType,
case    WHEN cb.borrowerType = 'Primary Borrower' THEN 1
ELSE 2 END as borrowerOrder
FROM ( SELECT   c.customerName, c.customerNumber,
'Primary Borrower'   AS     borrowerType,l.loanNumber
FROM    customer AS c INNER JOIN loan AS l
ON      c.customerId=l.customerId
UNION   SELECT  c.customerName, c.customerNumber, 
bt.borrowerTypeName AS borrowerType,l.loanNumber
    FROM    customer AS c 
    INNER JOIN coborrower AS cb
    ON      c.customerId=cb.customerId
    INNER JOIN  loan AS l
    ON          l.loanId=cb.loanId
    INNER JOIN  borrowerType AS bt
    ON          bt.borrowerTypeId=cb.borrowerTypeId
 ) AS cb
 INNER JOIN fnGetReportExceptions
('-1',   '-1',   'All',   '-1',   '-1',   'L',   
'All',   'All',   'All',   '0',
'-1',   '-1',   '-1')  func
ON  cb.loanNumber = func.loanNumber
GROUP BY cb.loanNumber, cb.customerName, cb.borrowerType
ORDER BY cb.loanNumber, borrowerOrder,borrowerType, cb.customerName
```

Messy I know but its what I have to work with.  This SQL pulls out my list of loans that have exceptions and any coborrowers below.  The thing is when I try to add in information from the function, it will product out because of the number of exceptions returned.

So for example.  When my selection becomes

```
SELECT
cb.loanNumber,
cb.customerName,
cb.borrowerType,
case    WHEN cb.borrowerType = 'Primary Borrower' THEN 1
ELSE 2 END as borrowerOrder, 
func.exceptionDefName
...
```

I get something like

```
loan Number  customerName    borrowerType     borrowerOrder  DefName
111          John Smith      Primary Borrower 1              Missng Sig
111          John Smith      Primary Borrower 1              Missng Doc
111          Wendy Smith     CoBorrower       2              Missng Sig
111          Wendy Smith     Coborrower       2              Missng Guar
111          Wendy Smith     Coborrower       2              Missing Doc
```

What I am looking for is:

```
loan Number  customerName    borrowerType       borrowerOrder DefName
111          John Smith      Primary Borrower   1             Missng Sig
                                                              Missng Doc
             Wendy Smith     CoBorrower         2             Missng Sig
                                                              Missng Guar
                                                              Missing Doc
```

I would do it through UNIONS and Selects, but it seems a bad way to do it given that I am referencing a function that can potentially cause a huge performance hit if this is a very general report that the customer wants.

Thanks

Comment: use CASE statements and ROW_NUMBER() to replace the value with an empty string if it's not the first row in that column's partition.   Though, really, depending on how you are delivering the report, it will probably perform much faster to do this in the front end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually wound up doing this in the front end of SSRS doing grouping within a group.  Then a child group from that.

It displayed the data perfectly to group first on the officer, then the loan, within that having a sub report as part of a group on the loan ID.